# Performance issue either System.out.println(" log information ") or use log4j logger file?

Tags: java, web, log4j

Can anyone please tell me in web applications which is the better way to store log information. If we use tomcat server internally the log information will be stored in log file. What is the better approach to log the application data console for trouble shooting either by using system.out.println(" log information here") or log4j log file to store log.
which one gives better performance when we are dealing the large application?

Comment: do not ever use System.out.println in anything that goes to production. Always use a logging framework.

Comment: thanks @Xsen, Any impact if we use sytem.out.println in production.

Comment: you cannot change what level of logging you get, you simply get everything. Also you cannot change where this goes, framework allow you to print to file, steam to other server... Also in some cases performance is better as the writing can be offloaded to a separate thread. Anyway, using system.out.println as a logging mechanism is wrong at ALL levels. This simply is not a logging mechanism, but an ugly way to print something on the console that is then somehow caught by your server and spooled to a log file. Also what happens if multiple threads print at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Logger is much better because you can configure appenders, size of the log file, log lever, rolling log files and many other things. 
Don't use System.out.println for any regular project. You can use it only if you have test project to verify if something in Java works like you think it should.

Comment: Hi Jakub, thanks. i am using tomcat server, the server is also maintaining the log files in logs folder. Is there any specific reason to use log4j except logger lever,rolling.. i mean to say any performance issue if use system.out.println

Comment: Performance will be much better with Logging framework as well. It's because System.out.println is a very slow I/O operation and it is synchronized, so only one thread can access this method at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

> Which one gives better performance when we are dealing the large application?

Besides the obvious reasons for using a logger (customizable output, filtering, file handling etc.), a logger normally yields better performance, beause of the following:

- the logger can provide information on the log level, i.e. if you have to build some expensive message for debugging, you can skip that if debug level is not available:

  `if( log.isDebugEnabled() ) { log.debug( buildSomeExpensiveOutput() ); }`

  This would only call `buildSomeExpensiveOutput()` if debug level logging is enabled and would save that cost if it isn't (e.g. in most production systems).
- writing to the console might slow down the application because execution might be synchronized, whereas most loggers write their logs asynchronously

Comment: @thomas.... "writing to the console might slow down the application because execution might be synchronized, whereas most loggers write their logs asynchronously "., this will suite for my question, because System is instatiated only once and it will handle only one at a time to write into the console where as log4j can writes the logs into the files asynchronously, that gives better performance. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

It is much better to use logging framework (logback,  log4j2) because you can fine tune log level without recompilation. For exmaple you find out that you do not need some information - decrease log level from info to error. Or you face issue - increase it to debug or trace.

The performance cost of using log framework is small. You must be careful about concatenation of strings, especially if log level is disabled:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("Value = " + value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a logger is probably the better approach for a number of reasons:

**Turn off certain log levels**

You can turn off logs at the debug level when developement is complete, if you used s.o.p, you would have to comment out/remove them

**Log anywhere**

You can easily choose to log to a file/email/sms without changing your code, you only need to change configuration.

Also, from the [log4j(1.2) home page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), some performance info is given:

> On an AMD Duron clocked at 800Mhz running JDK 1.3.1, it costs about 5 nanoseconds to determine if a logging statement should be logged or not. Actual logging is also quite fast, ranging from 21 microseconds using the SimpleLayout, 37 microseconds using the TTCCLayout. The performance of the PatternLayout is almost as good as the dedicated layouts, except that it is much more flexible.